# Can't give width on paragraph tag

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using a WP shortcode which doesn't give me an option to have a width or any styling.

[image]

```
<div style="border: 1px solid rgb(154, 154, 154); background: #fff; padding: 10px 20px 203px 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; ">[form id="165617" filter="limited" </span>limit="1"]
</div>
```

The page can seen here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp

For some reason no matter how I put CSS and try to target it like:
width: 200px !important. It doesn't respond.

Do you have any idea on how to manipulate this and what are the proper CSS, id or class that I can target for the text to conform to a widht?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to specify a `width` to the `<p>`? You see the text that way because it doesn't have any spaces. Add `word-wrap: break-word` to the `<p>` and you will see it is working.

Comment: if I add it within a <span> it doesn't work either.

Comment: It doesn't matter which tag you use, if the content is one long word (no spaces in it), you need to add `word-wrap`. Or add `overflow: auto` to the parent `<div>`.

Comment: As @azeós mentioned, you can use word-wrap property to control long words and in addition, use these to add hyphens at the end to show that its a continous word: 

   -webkit-hyphens: auto;
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
   hyphens: auto;

Answer (score 0):

use `word-break:break-word;` for the paragraph tag.

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp